# Only get part of text from element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get only part of text from element that looks like this

```
<td class="coeff">
   <abbr title="Thibault Tricole - set">2<sup>1-2</sup><span class="minor"> - lay</span></abbr></td>
```

Is it possible to only get "2" from element and not "1-2" and "-lay" so output is only "2"

Comment: Can you use `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely never really used it

Comment: I've posted an example using bs4.

Comment: @JakeM Using bs4 you are actually compromising with the advantages offered by Selenium ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to get the `2` from the HTML snippet from the question:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '''\
<td class="coeff">
   <abbr title="Thibault Tricole - set">2<sup>1-2</sup><span class="minor"> - lay</span></abbr>
</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

first_text = soup.find('abbr').contents[0]
print(first_text)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine that with `marketonly = (WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'coeff')]//abbr")))).text` beacuse the values change but xpath stays the same

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in achieving this using `Selenium` and `JS`, refer below:

Try this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# using CSS Selector
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.coeff abbr")))

# Or using XPath
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//abbr[@title='Thibault Tricole - set']")))

# Or using XPath
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'coeff')]//abbr")))

# Below code should extract the value 2
abbr_text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", element)

print(abbr_text)
```

**Console output:**

```
2
```